# Tesseract OCR 4.x beta for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I'm trying to work with text recognition on raspberry pi for a project of mine. I've installed tesseract ocr v4.0.0 beta on my Windows computer, and I'm trying to install this version as well on the RPi, but I only manage to install the 3.0.3 version. I don't know if it is possible to install de 4.x beta on RPi.

I assume it must be possibe since on the [github page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki) there is an installation guide for some Linux distros. The one I tried is for Debian Strech, since Raspian is based on this, but well, it installed 3.0.3.

I was wondering is anyone can tell me if this is possible or has a guide for me to achieve this.

Comment: It looks like you're going to have to build it from git.  Try [these instructions](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling-%E2%80%93-GitInstallation).

Comment: Please note that questions should not be cross posted to multiple sites on the Stackexchange network. Please pick one and delete the other. Thanks.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn thank you! I'll try this and let you know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raspbian is Debian based therefore we should follow the instructions for installing on Debian.

However following [these instructions](https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr/) shows that this repo doesn't support the `armhf` architecture.

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr/stretch stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

I was able to build from the Git source and install using the following commands from [these instructions](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling-%E2%80%93-GitInstallation):

> ```
> $ git clone --depth 1  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract.git 
> $ cd tesseract-ocr/
> $ ./autogen.sh
> $ ./configure
> $ make
> $ sudo make install
> $ sudo ldconfig
> $ tesseract -v
>
> tesseract 4.0.0-beta.3
> leptonica-1.74.1
> libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.1) : libpng 1.6.28 : libtiff 4.0.8 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.5.2 : libopenjp2 2.1.2
> ```

Hey, guess what ... it works!

> ```
> $ tesseract img.png outputbase
> Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0-beta.3 with Leptonica
>
> $ more outputbase.txt
> The (quick) [brown] {fox} jumps!
> Over the $43,456.78 <lazy> #90 dog
> & duck/goose, as 12.5% of E-mail
> from aspammer@website.com is spam.
> Der ,schnelle” braune Fuchs springt
> iiber den faulen Hund. Le renard brun
> «rapide» saute par-dessus le chien
> paresseux. La volpe marrone rapida
> salta sopra il cane pigro. El zorro
> marron ripido salta sobre el perro
> perezoso. A raposa marrom ripida
> salta sobre o cdo preguigoso.
> ```

For this image: [image: Test image for OCR]

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer! I tried it, but I'm getting the error that is suggested in the compiling guide you left me on the comment. I tried using the autorecong -i but it didn't work. Do you think I have to first install tesseract-ocr via apt install and then tried the compiling guide ? Thanks!

Comment: @Jhon I didn't have to install tesseract-ocr.  I'm Raspbian Stretch 9.  What version are you running?

Comment: Raspbian 8 (jessie)

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to Raspbian 9 Stretch or try using a different SD Card with Stretch preinstalled.  I didn't have any issues building OpenCV on Stretch.  Although it was built for Python 3 and the opencv-people-counter project is using Python 2 syntax.

Comment: I'd like to thank you a lot man! It worked with Raspbian 9!

Answer (score -1):

you'll find a version 4 in the stretch-backports repository.

Comment: OP is running Raspbian Jessie and AFAIK there is no Raspbian Stretch backports repo. How should OP install it?

Comment: He can use the arm packages from debian stretch-backports.   armel or armhf, depending on his hardware.

Comment: I don't think you should assume OP knows this. Maybe you should update your answer with this information